# How to correctly set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ehcache

What value should the parameter `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri` have when using Spring Boot with Hibernate?

I've initially set it to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri=classpath:ehcache.xml` and the cache was initiated correctly, however, JUnit Tests were failing.

After long searching I've found information that Hibernate expect the parameter in the form `classpath://ehcache.xml` . After using that notation the JUnit tests were green, but the normal application refused to start.

Now I'm forced to edit `application.properties` each time I'm going to start JUnit tests, and I can't use JUnit test in the build pipeline, because I can't commit the parameter with which the server wouldn't start.

How to set that parameter correctly so that both the application and the test would run?

Comment: You can define application.properties in test classpath, where you will override `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri`. How exactly to do that depends on build framework you are using. With maven you can add `src/test/resources/application.properties`